# search_after with spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Has anyone successfully used search_after with spring-data-elasticsearch?

I've added _uid to my sort which is correctly getting put in my Pageable by the @Controller.  I turned on the slow query log and validated if I manually run the query the @Repository generates,  I get in the response:

```
    "sort": [
      1522270372773,
      "log#AWJuYn7SAKReCIGzMYda"
    ]
```

I added into my pojo (the class returned by the @Repository):

```
 @JsonProperty("sort")
 String[] sort;
```

Sort is always coming back as null.    Tried a couple different things and cannot figure out how to get sort to be set.   Any ideas?

Comment: one thing which occurred to me is the first item in the array is not a string.   Interesting the elasticsearch people made an array with mixed types when elasticsearch itself does not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem but discovered some disappointing details.

The culprit is here:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/3.0.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/DefaultResultMapper.java

In the mapResults method,  the code populates my POJO from SearchHit.sourceAsString().     sourceAsString provides a subset of the original JSON which does not include the sort array, i.e.

```
   "sort": [
      1522270147602,
      "log#AWJuXxJ_AKReCIGzMYdV"
    ]
```

The access modifiers (privates with no getters and finals) did not provide for an elegant enhancement.  I ended up copying DefaultResultMapper and implementing a method similar to setPersistentEntityId which sets sortValues into my pojo.  The impl for this method is as follows:

```
private <T> void setSearchSortValues(T result, Object[] sortValues, Class<T> clazz) {

    if(SortAware.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        ((SortAware) result).setSortValues(sortValues);
    }

}
```

My POJO implements the SortAware interface which I defined as follows:

```
public interface SortAware {

    public Object[] getSortValues();

    public void setSortValues(Object[] sortValues);

}
```